# Enable multicurrency feature in magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento

I am using magento 1.9 with ultimo responsive theme.

As i want to enable multi currency drop down in my homepage. I use the code from [this site](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-currency-selector-to-magentos-header/).

After proper coding on the pages i get an error on homepage:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?>', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\design\frontend\ultimo\default\template\page\html\header.phtml on line 258. from the line statement.

Related code:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
<p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getWelcome() ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></p>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
<!-- START How to add Currency selector to Magento's header -->
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('custom_currency_selector') ?>
<!-- END   How to add Currency selector to Magento's header -->.
```

So please help me in this matter. and enable multi currency dropdown. as I am new to magento.

Comment: Paste content of header.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('directory/currency')->setTemplate('directory/currency.phtml')->toHtml() ?>
```